# Change username and password in postman API

Tags: python, api, postman

I ran an API in postman and it's working fine. Here's the code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://sct.intutrack.com/api/prod/login'
payload = {}
headers = {}
response = requests.request('POST', url, headers = headers, data = payload, allow_redirects=False, timeout=undefined, allow_redirects=false)
print(response.text)
```

when I check the python code in postman it gives me:

```
import requests

url = "https://sct.intutrack.com/api/prod/login"

payload = ""
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.15.0",
    'Accept': "*/*",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "33e50c20-f264-4b65-8fc8-7016b3315134,8b5414b1-4b79-4749-91d7-80daa4d4ecbe",
    'Host': "sct.intutrack.com",
    'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate",
    'content-length': "",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

I have an API username and password(which I passed in Authorization) but I am unable to find the same in the python code. How can I change them?

Result in Jupyter Notebook:

```
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, you probably shouldnt expose your prod/login url here. Secondly, the header and payload in postman API above has no username and password. How do you want to sent them in python? Your question is a little confusing, can you please clarify

Comment: The username and password are entered in the "Authorization" tab of postman and it somehow uses them and gives a response but when I retrieve the code and run it in jupyter notebook it returne a 400 Bad request

Comment: You might considering adding auth parameter to your request. Something like - `requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, auth=(username, password))`

Comment: @NishantPatel I did that, It returns the same

Comment: So heres the Postman Code generator, when you pass the username and password it encrypt the details as Base64, so say your `username = 'ok'` and `password = '12345'`, it will encrypt `ok:12345` to `b2s6MTIzNDU=` and add authorisation tab as
`headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json", 'Authorisation': "Basic b2s6MTIzNDU=",.......}`
So you can generate your own Base 64 string and edit the Authorisation key.

Answer (score -1):

You should put your the json string containing username and password 
in the following box: [image: here]
Then click the code in python and it will show the right code like this:
[image: here]

SAME AS SET

```
payload = "{\"username\": \"\",\"password\": \"xxxxxx\",\"remeber\":0}"
```

Comment: This may sound stupid but I have options till GraphQL